# org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Missing or invalid type argument for pointer action

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing automation for screen: http://todomvc.com/examples/angularjs/#/

My test is:
1) Add new todo item.
2) Save
3) Update text in the item 
4) Verify it is updated.

My code for third step is:

```
toDoElem = getToDoByText( textBefore );
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(toDoElem);
Thread.sleep(1000);
action.doubleClick(toDoElem).perform();
toDoElem.sendKeys(textAfter);
toDoElem.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

The code fails on line

```
action.doubleClick(toDoElem).perform();
```

The error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Missing or invalid type argument for pointer action
```

What can I do?

The stack is:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Missing or invalid type argument for pointer action
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'sbmelmac-07474.local', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:f65c:89ff:fea1:a07b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.5', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, appBuildId=20161129173726, version=50.0.2, platform=MAC, proxy=Proxy(), command_id=1.0, specificationLevel=0.0, acceptSslCerts=false, processId=87293.0, browserVersion=50.0.2, platformVersion=15.5.0, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=darwin}]
Session ID: 527b84cf-b7a1-4145-997c-d1ea6a00fb6c
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.perform(RemoteWebDriver.java:703)
  at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions$BuiltAction.perform(Actions.java:631)
  at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.perform(Actions.java:593)
```

Comment: Which line are you seeing the error? Can you update the full error stack trace?

Comment: It fails on perform(); The stack is attached to the question.

Comment: Manually, I am able to put some text within `todos` textbox but how do I `Save`?

Comment: Just click enter

Comment: Can you show what you are doing in `getToDoByText( textBefore )`?

Comment: public WebElement getToDoByText( String text){
        System.out.print("TEXT:"+text);
        toDoElem = wait.until( ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated( By.xpath("//*[@id='todo-list']//li/div/label[text()='"+text+"']") ) );
        return toDoElem;
    }

Comment: if the browser is firefox, gecko does not support Actions as of now, i hope. So on which browser this exception?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
action.doubleClick(toDoElem).perform();
```

to

```
action.doubleClick(toDoElem).build().perform();
```

You need to build the action before performing it

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code I think it solve your issue

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(toDoElem);
action.doubleClick(toDoElem).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to the bug in webdriver:
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/659